# cURL to Ruby net/http with Post and Get

Tags: ruby, curl, salesforce

I am attempting to convert a cURL request into its Ruby equivalent. This is the cURL request and the xml file it is referencing is the same as the xml variable below;

```
curl -H "X-SFDC-Session: sessionId" -H "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8" -d @create-job.xml https://instance.salesforce.com/services/async/30.0/job
```

This is the ruby method I have come up with;

```
def create_salesforce_batch_job(object_name, salesforce_token)
  xml = <<-XML
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <jobInfo
      xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
    <operation>query</operation>
    <object>#{object_name}</object>
    <concurrencyMode>Parallel</concurrencyMode>
    <contentType>CSV</contentType>
  </jobInfo>
  XML
  uri = URI.parse("https://na1.salesforce.com/services/async/30.0/job/")
  headers = {'X-SFDC-Session' => salesforce_token, 'Content-Type' => "application/xml; charset=UTF-8"}
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, headers)
  request.body = xml

  response = http.request(request)
end
```

but I keep getting HTTPBadRequest responses when I use my Ruby method, using the same credentials and xml with cURL returns the expected values. Where am I going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Your curl will do a POST,but your ruby code appears to be doing a GET,it needs to do POST as well.

Comment: Also, the body with the 400 response will have more details about what was wrong with the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the [cURB gem](https://github.com/taf2/curb)? It's a libcurl wrapper, which maps more closely to cURL than Net::HTTP will.

There are a number of examples, from simple GET to more complex, including showing how to use authentication and set headers.